# When to use @property?

Tags: objective-c, performance, properties

Should one use `@property` for variables that will be accessed very often, such as the position of a particle? `@property` creates getters and setter for a variable which adds the overhead of calling a method. In most situations this is not noticeable, but what if the property is accessed up to a million times a second (within different instances)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the Objective-C runtime will add a certain amount of overhead for `@property` accessors. However, this is the accepted way to share information between Objective-C classes. You should only consider a different approach if you have measured your application and determined that the `@property` overhead is actually a processing bottleneck.

Keep in mind that a modern processor operates in the *GHz* range, and something happening "a million times per second" is only in the *MHz* range. Chances are, your bottlenecks will be somewhere else.

If you *do* have a problem, you can always do your particle processing on an array of simple `Particle` structures inside of a larger Objective-C `ParticleCloud` class. That would allow the rest of your program to ignore the exact implementation of the `Particle` objects, while removing the need for `@property` accessors.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually using the getter and setter? If not, don't use a property. If so, use it. The only way to know if the overhead is significant is to do your own performance testing and record the time before and after the process, running the exact same simulation and comparing the time elapsed. If it's a performance hit, but negligible, don't worry about it. You might even find that it's FASTER w/ the @property than whatever other method you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use a `@property` for properties of your object. I know it sounds dumb, but by property I mean "public" attributes that can be accessed by other classes. If only your class will need that attribute, then keep it private inside your implementation and things will be smoother and cleaner.

One of the benefits of the @property is that you can specify if you want them to be read only (i.e. no setter). So it's really a question of public API.